# Proof of cross product and dot product relationship?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, inner-products, cross-product

Let $r(t)$ be a smooth vector function with values in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $|r(t)| = 2$ for all $t$. Why does the dot product of $|r(t)|$ and $|r'(t)|$ = the cross product of $|r(t)|$ and $|r'(t)|$?

Comment: I've done my best to format your question, but it makes no sense, because the moduli of vectors are scalars, so you can't take dot or cross products  between them.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've done my best to interpret your question, and I believe that you wanted your question to state:

Let $r(t)$ be a smooth vector function with values in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $|r(t)|=2$ for all $t$. Why does $|r(t) \cdot r'(t)| = |r(t) \times r'(t)|$?

It's important to know that taking the modulus of a vector always yields a scalar. The dot product and cross product ONLY can be applied to vectors.

Now to the restated version of your question, we know $u \cdot v = |u||v|\cos(\theta)$ and $u \times v = |u||v|\sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between u and v. Thus, $|r(t) \cdot r'(t)| = |r(t) \times r'(t)|$ can be restated as $|\cos(\theta)| = |\sin(\theta)|$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $r(t)$ and $r'(t)$. So for this statement to be true, we're looking for the angle between your function and your derivative to be $\pi/4$ (or some sister angle).

Now since the modulus of $r(t)$ is 2 for all t, $r(t)$ has a constant distance of 2 from the origin. Thus, r lies on a sphere of radius 2. However, I do not see how this condition would enforce the necessary conditions. For example, let
$r(t) = < 2\cos(t),2\sin(t),0 >$ has modulus 2 for all t, lies on the sphere of radius 2, but $r(t)$ is orthonormal to $r'(t)$ ($\theta = \pi/2$).

So, all of that to say, that either I've misinterpreted your question or that your hypothesis is false.

Comment: Maybe the OP means $|r|·|r'|=|r\times r'|$, true with the given constraints, because the dot is read as "dot product". The meaning of the signs depend more often on the context than it seems.